# Passing parameters to singleton class / static constructor

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, singleton, static-constructor

I have a `Listener` class to listen on a particular HTTP port.
I made `Listener` singleton (since there will always be a single listener object listening on a particular port). 
For this I made **default `Listener()`** contructor `private`. Made `Listener` instance (inside `Listener` class) `static` and have `static Listener` constructor initialize singleton `Listener` object. Also have `static Listener getListener()` which returns singleton `Listener` instance.

I am receiving a SOAP on this port which my listener callback method is processing.

Now I want date time of last notification pushed to my UI.

So what I thought is somehow while initializing `Listener` I will pass a delegate, a reference to which will be stored inside `Listener` and then every time I receive a notification, inside listener callback I will call that delegate and pass it current time (`new DateTime()`), which will do necessary task of printing message with time. I also thought of making delegate parameter optional so that if delegate is `null` it will not be called at all on notification. However since I made constructor private, I am not able to figure it out how I can pass delegate to it.

To summarize and generalize the whole question: How to pass a parameter (to be stored as a instance member) to singleton class?

Should I pass delegate to `getListener()`? and inside it check every-time if delegate is null and if not, set it?
But then if I am accessing this singleton object too many times by calling `Listener.getListener()`, everytime it will unnecessarily check the delegate is `null`. In fact thats why I moved initializing `Listener` to static constructor just to avoid checking if `Listener` is initialized everytime `getListener()` is called.

What should I do to pass parameter to singleton class? Or this checks in `getListener()` inevitable?

**Note:** I don't know but this question may boil down to how can we pass parameters to static constructor since we need to initialize things first time the class is used and we have to initialize it with delegate/other programmatic construct (thus we cannot load initialization parameters from some config file inside static constructor).

Comment: Why not raise an event from the singleton class that notifies the UI of the last request time? or have a property that is always set to this value which can be queried by the UI thread.

Comment: raising event means again calling a callback which will be delegate only - I guess, and setting value means requiring UI thread to perform polling - may not reflect updates immediately?

Comment: Events are delegates in essence; so it would not be more taxing then calling a delegate handed to the method.  Also, as the delegate is associated with the object, it would be easier to add multiple listeners to the event. Consider the observer pattern - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx

Comment: Yess, thats fine that it will be delegate, the point is how will I register/pass that delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a normal event to your singleton class:

```
public class Listener
{
  //declare a delegate for the event
  public delegate void InformationDelegate(DateTime timestamp);

  //declare the event using the delegate
  public event InformationDelegate Information;

  public void SomeFunction()
  {
    // do something...
    if(Information != null)
    {
      Information(DateTime.Now);
    }
  }

  // singleton handling etc... 
}
```

Then every object that wants to get informed registers itself on the singleton instance:

```
class SomeUIClass
{
  void AFunction()
  {
    Listener.Instance.Information += InformationHandling;
  }

  public void InformationHandling(DateTime timestamp)
  {
    // do something with the information
  }
}
```

Thanks to @Kami for clarifying the topic!

Comment: yes that seems to be the only option, and also the preferred one, I guess